# Can I set tsconfig baseUrl to "./src"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, path, base-url

The nextjs project is being developed with typescript.

All modules related to the app are created in the src directory.

So, I am trying to set the absolute path based on src by adding src to `baseUrl` of `tsconfig`.

However, I am concerned about the side effect of setting the `baseUrl` to the src directory rather than the project root.

So my two questions are below.

1. Is there any side effect when `baseUrl` is set as src in tsconfig?
2. Would it be better to manage the path with tsconfig's `paths`? Or would it be better to just change the `baseUrl`?

Comment: The OG `pages` directory can be put under `src`, but I'm not sure the new `app` directory can. I'd test. If it can't be, then the `baseUrl` set to `src` won't help as the setting was intended. Using `paths` seems to be the better option with the new `app` directory.